# Fuzzification of Image based on Histogram

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Here, i am interested to discuss how to fuzzify an image (membership plan) from gray level [0-255].

I found one example image below.
[image]

I know about creating histogram of an image. but not sure how can we define membership value of gray-level.

Does anyone have idea? Please share thanks

Comment: I don't understand that diagram regarding the histogram and the intensity profiles.  Can you please explain what the steps are to "fuzzify" an image?

Comment: @rayryeng  Sure.. i will edit this question and summarize methods as well. thank you for your interest.